# After installing Visual Studio 2010 SP1 TeamCity Agent doesn't recognize NAnt Buildrunner

Tags: visual-studio-2010, teamcity, nant, teamcity-5.0

i've recently updated one of my TeamCity Agents to Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Since then several Buildrunner are not supported on this Agent anymore (esp. NAnt-Runner)! I could reproduce this behavior on another agent. This happens after the installation of the service pack 1. I've upgraded an agent to visual studio 2010 without sp1 and all buildrunners are still available. I compared the enviroment-varibles of the agents, but i couldn't find any significant differences.

Hope you've got some answers for me!

Edit:
Agent without VS2010 SP1 has following Build-Runners:
Ant. Duplicates finder (.NET), Duplicates finder (Java), FxCop, Inspections, Ipr, Maven2, **MSBuild**, **NAnt**, Rake, Command Line, **sln2003**, **sln2005**, **sln2008**

Available Buildrunners after the upgrade:
Ant, Duplicates finder (.NET), Duplicates finder (Java), FxCop, Inspections, Ipr, Maven2, Rake, Command Line

Edit2:
An excerpt from the agent-log:
INFO - gent.msBuild.MSBuildRunnerBase - Runner MSBuild is not registered: Microsoft .Net Framework 2.0/3.5/4.0 or Mono are required
INFO - ver.agent.nant.NAntBuildRunner - Runner NAnt is not registered: Mono or Microsoft .Net Framework 1.1 or 2.0 is required
INFO - ver.agent.nant.NAntBuildRunner - Runner sln2003 is not registered: Mono or Microsoft .Net Framework 1.1 or 2.0 is required
INFO - gent.msBuild.MSBuildRunnerBase - Runner sln2005 is not registered: Microsoft .Net Framework 2.0/3.5/4.0 or Mono are required
INFO - gent.msBuild.MSBuildRunnerBase - Runner sln2008 is not registered: Microsoft .Net Framework 2.0/3.5/4.0 or Mono are required

Somewho he cannot recognize the .net-framework anymore. I checked, which Versions are installed: .Net 2.0 SP2, .Net 3.0 SP2, .Net 3.5 SP1 and .Net 4 Client/Extended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i solved my problem by adding the following lines to the agent.properties:

```
system.DotNetFramework2.0
system.DotNetFramework3.5
system.DotNetFramework4.0
env.MSBuild=%system.DotNetFramework3.5_x86_Path%
```

Now my agent has the same build-runners available as before the upgrade :)
Seems as if the autodetection of teamcity 5.0-agents cannot handle visual studio 2010 Sp1